# Generate choose on custom data type with 2 options

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am trying to achieve something very simple.
I have this data type :

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import System.Random
data Letter = G | B deriving(Show, Eq, Bounded)

arbitraryLetter :: Gen Letter
arbitraryLetter = choose (G,B)
```

I am compiling and getting this error

```
    • No instance for (Random Letter) arising from a use of ‘choose’
    • In the expression: choose (G, B)
      In an equation for ‘arbitraryLetter’:
      arbitraryLetter = choose (G, B)
```

Why isn't this working?
I want to be able to use QuickCheck on this data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choose` has type `Random a => (a, a) -> Gen a`, so `choose (G, B)` requires a `Random` instance for your `Letter` type. If you want to create a generator from a set of values you can use `elements` instead:

```
arbitraryLetter :: Gen Letter
arbitraryLetter = elements [G, B]
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I generate 1 and print to the console? I tried running arbitraryLetter and got an error :  • No instance for (Show (Gen Letter))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: @Eyzuky - You can use `sample` in ghci: `sample arbitraryLetter`.